# Change SwitchMaterial color dinamicaly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-styles, material-components-android, android-switch

In my app, the first activity is a selector where i can select between 3 buttons: red, green, yellow. When i select one button, a new activity is displayed with a SwitchMaterial. Now i want to change the colorControlActivated so that the switch color is red if i have selected the red button, green for the green button and so on. How can i do that?

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                        android:id="@+id/profile_setting_switch1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:theme="@style/SwitchTecnoTheme"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profile_setting_1"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_setting_1" />
```

```
<style name="SwitchTecnoTheme" >
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/tecno_brand_color</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define 3 different selectors and use something like:

```
    switch.isUseMaterialThemeColors = false
    switch.thumbTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.thumb_selector)
    switch.trackTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.track_selector)
```

where `thumb_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/switchTrackDisable"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/switchThumbActive" />
  <item android:color="@color/switchThumbkNormal" />
</selector>
```

and `track_selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/switchTrackDisable"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/switchTrackActive" />
  <item android:color="@color/switchTrackNormal" />
</selector>
```